# Relations question - need clarification to understand better

Tags: equivalence-relations

Please see the question which shows you two questions and two answers. Are the 2 answers contradicting each other? Can someone clarify please.

[image: Relations quesion]

Question 1 Answer says "DOES NOT IMPLY THAT ALL X and Y...." but Question 4 answers says "IMPLIES FOR ALL X and Y

Comment: Please type out all images. Images are not searchable and some users will get a bad impression, among other issues. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The first red underlined question of the OP is the same one as he has asked half an hour ago in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2271144) but he/she doesn't mention it !!! This question should be closed.

Comment: Read again. They are not same.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of [symmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) is:

> for every $a,b \in X \ (aRb \Leftrightarrow bRa)$.

This means that, for every pair of element $a,b$: either $a,b$ and $b,a$ are $R$-related or neither $a,b$ nor $b,a$ are.

If $aRb \Leftrightarrow bRa$, obviously $aRb \Rightarrow bRa$, and this explain Q4's answer: if $R$ is symm, then $xRy$ implies $yRx$, for every $x,y$.

But the def of symmetry does not mean that every pair $a,b$ must be $R$-related.

This explain why it is not true that $xRy$ and $yRx$.

---

Consider the trivial example with the symmetric relation: $\text { is brother of }$.

Obviously, if $\text {John is brother of Jim }$, then $\text {Jim is brother of John }$, but this does not mean that every two men in the world are brothers (at least in the "biological" sense...).

---

In more formal terms, we have that form the definition of *symmetry* we derive correctly that: $∀x \ ∀y \ (xRy → yRx)$.

From the wrong answer above, insted, we derive: $∀x \ ∀y \ (xRy)$, that is not licensed by the definition of *symmetry*.

Comment: Thanks Mauro. I really like the brother analogy. I am from a non native English speaking country. The sentence **Relation R on a set X is symmetric, then xRy and yRx for all x,y E X** and **R to be symmetric on X, we have that if xRy for x,y E X then yRx also** have two different meanings I guess.

Comment: @Sanone - two aspects; one is related to propositional logic: $p \to q$ (**if xRy, then yRx**) is not the same as $p \land q$ (**xRy and yRx**).

Comment: The other is the def of symm: **R is symm** iff: for all $x,y \in X$ (**xRy iff yRx**). From this we have that: if **R is symm**, then **xRy iff yRx** and thus (the iff is a bi-conditional, i.e. the conjunctions of the two separated conditionals)  if **R is symm**, then **if xRy, then yRx**.

Answer (score 0):

In both answers a symmetric relation on $Y$ is described as a relation that has the property: $$xRy\implies yRx\text{ for all }x,y\in Y\tag1$$
It is evidently not true that $(1)$ implies that $xRy$ for every pair $x,y\in Y$.

This fact is mentioned in the first answer (where $Y=X$) as some extra information, and is **not** mentioned in the second answer (where $Y=S$).